# How do I work out how to address an object in order to prototype it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to prototype an object but the problem is, I don't know how to address the object before I use it.

```
??????.prototype.writeObj = function( obj ) {
    this.write( JSON.stringify(obj) );
}

tls.createServer(options, function (s) {
    s.writeObj( {command:'addjob', options:{} } );
}
```

The important thing for me here is to find out how to go about finding this out, if that makes sense. I've tried reading the node documentation, but it does....oh hang on a sec.

I will continue anyway, turns out ????? is stream.Stream.  Without reading the manual *sic*, is there an easy way to find this out in code?

Comment: stream.Stream !!!!!!! haha, after sometimes writing the question leads to the answer

Comment: 2 votes to close, yet there is no answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

The ES5 method lets you find the prototype.

`Object.getPrototypeOf(s) === stream.Stream`

There is a similar utility method called [`.isPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf)

`stream.Stream.isPrototypeOf(s)`

Comment: And don't forget the **documentation**.

Comment: This rings a bell, thanks.  Is this as good as it gets in JavaScript? I mean, it can check what I have found, but it does not find it in the first place.

Comment: @tomwrong it get's the prototype. It can't possibly tell you _where_ you can find the prototype. I guess you can load all node.js modules and walk over them looking for objects that are the same as the prototype. It can't possibly return "stream.Stream" ;)

Comment: I feared as much. It would be nice if there was the ability to do just that using reflection or something. Nevermind, I'll live.